# How to get limited number of fields from embedded document with mongodb-odm?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm

I want to get the result of this mongodb command with Doctrine MongoDB ODM:

```
db.posts.find({_id: 3}, {comments: {$slice: [0, 5]}})
```

I was looking for it, but didn't find anything, neither in the documentation. If you have any idea, please help, thank you.

Here are my document classes:

```
/** @ODM\Document(db="dbname" collection="posts") */
class Posts{

    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $_id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $some_field;

    /** @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Comment") */
    private $comments = array();

    public function getSomeField() { return $this->some_field; }
    public function setSomeField($content) { $this->some_field = $content; }

    public function getComments() { return $this->comments; }
    public function addComment(Comment $comment) { $this->comments[] = $comment; }
}

/** @ODM\EmbeddedDocument */
class Comment {

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $timeStamp;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $message;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Users", simple=true) */
    private $user_ref;

    public function getTimeStamp() { return $this->timeStamp; }
    public function setTimeStamp($str) { $this->timeStamp = $str;}

    public function getMessage() { return $this->message; }
    public function setMessage($str) { $this->message = $str; }

    public function getUser() { return $this->user_ref; }
    public function setUser(Users $user) { $this->user_ref = $user; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While documentation on query builder's [`->select()`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#selecting-fields) doesn't go much into details nor methods alike, following code will allow you to run your command:

```
$qb = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(Posts::class)
        ->selectSlice('comments', 0, 5)
        ->field('_id')->equals(3);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->execute();
```